# Total API Request Allocations Exceeded During Peak Days

Tags: api, integration, architecture

**The problem:**

I find the [Salesforce Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm) on Total API Request Allocations topic a little bit contradictory.

> If your org reaches or exceeds its daily API request limit, Salesforce still allows the operations to proceed by a certain amount, if possible. This helps avoid blocking your workflows during unexpected spikes in workloads and occasional peak periods.

The above quote seems in conflict with the following:

> A hard cap is in place to safeguard platform resources and prevent API requests from exceeding the daily limit unimpeded.

**Example scenario:**

We are implementing Salesforce for B2C with many integrations towards Salesforce due to different commerce platforms being connected to it. Our org needs 10 million inbound API calls a month and our org has 400 000 available calls per 24 hours, calculated as per the [Total API Request Allocations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm). Let's divide that by 28, a minimum amount of days you might get a month and we get around 357 142 inbound calls a day.

After a couple sessions with the customer, you find out that the number of inbound calls peaks on Monday and bottoms on Friday. On Monday it is over 400 000, on Friday it is around 200 000.

**The questions:**

1. Will there be a hard cap if the API limit is exceeded every Monday?
2. Do we need to contact Salesforce to buy additional API calls per 24 hours if we exceed the limit one day a week?

Comment: personally, I'd buy more API for peace of mind